# Javascript React redirect if session variable is set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using react. I have a login page which I don't want the user to be able to visit if a variable is set to true.

I am using sessionStorage after the user logs in and setting a variable to true:

```
 sessionStorage.setItem('loggedin', 'true');
```

My problem is that the use is still able to visit the login page.

How do I disallow the use to visit this page if loggedin is set to true?

Here's my current App Component:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={contact} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>In main component (`<App/>`), put the logic code inside `ComponentWillMount()` or `constructor` to check `loggedIn` status, then put inside `render()` condition to render page or not.</del>

UPDATE: you want to stop people who logged in to access `login` page, I update my answer: in `LoginComponent` check if `loggedIn`, do redirect to root. Router in my example is `ReactRouter`.

e.g :

```
Class LoginComponent extends React.Components {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.loggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem('loggedin') === 'true';

    }

    render() {
       // my example using reactRouter
       if(!this.loggedIn) {
           return <Redirect to='/'/>;
       }
       return (<div>Your Login content</div>)
    }

}
```

Comment: This works great but it's restricting access to all other pages too. How can I just restrict access to the login page?

Comment: @unzip700 I updated the answer, please have a look and see if it fix your issue :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `onEnter` function to `Route` Component which will be called when a user hits the corresponding URL. Just check here that user is loggedin. If he is `loggedin` and wants to go to Login component, just redirect to your `Home` component otherwise go as it is.

```
export function onEnter(nextState, transition, callback) {
  const { pathname } = nextState.location
  const isLoggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem('loggedin') === 'true'
  if (pathname === '/login' && isLoggedIn) {
    transition('/') //redirect to Home component
  }
  return callback() // go as it is.
}


class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} onEnter={onEnter}/>
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={contact} onEnter={onEnter}/>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} onEnter={onEnter}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Note: I have tested in react-router version 3.0 not higher.

Comment: This example only has in mind either the Home page or the login page. I only want to login page restricted. All other pages should have all access. I've updated my question and added my current app component code. Hope it helps. thanks